# Xamarin Android Margins for all resolutions

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I want my application to be the same on all resolutions and devices (phones). I searched the Internet for a solution, but they all deal with styles in [XAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language). My application is in XML and I don't know how to solve it. The following example

#### Visual Studio

[image]

It is okay and also on phone LG K10 Lite 2017 and LG K9 everything is good.

But, for example, on [Xiaomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi) mi Play 4, it’s not good :/

Sizes are good, but margins are different.

[image]

How can I fix it?

My XML Code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="55dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="12.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="55dp">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="12.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="55dp">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="12.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="55dp">
    </Button>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleViewText"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counterText"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        app:cpb_progressbar_color="#1A9CAC"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="#083A5F"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="7dp"
        app:cpb_progress="0"
        app:cpb_progress_max="10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/circularProgressBar1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is not Xamarin Forms.  This is Xamarin Android

Comment: @FileEX Personally I would use a `ConstraintLayout` ...

Comment: @SushiHangover It will be helped?

Comment: @SushiHangover The same result.

Comment: @FileEX If only the background image not works, you'd better use different resolutions images and put them in matched folders of **Resources**.(`mipmap-hdpi/mipmap-mdpi/mipmap-xhdpi/...`) You could have a look at this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/resources-for-varying-screens?tabs=windows .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT i mean buttons margins/positions

Comment: @FileEX Okey, you could have a  look at this document: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes